# How do i programatically determine whether a pod is in crashloopbackoff

Tags: go, kubernetes

Is there a way to determine programatically if a pod is in crashloopbackoff?
I tried the following

```
pods,err :=  client.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
if err != nil { 
    return err
}
for _, item := range pods.Items {
   log.Printf("found pod %v with state %v  reason %v and phase %v that started at %v",
                item.Name, item.Status.Message, item.Status.Reason, item.Status.Phase, item.CreationTimestamp.Time)
}
```

However this just prints blank for state and reason, tough it prints the phase.

Comment: It's hiding in [`ContainerStateWaiting.Reason`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1#ContainerStateWaiting): `kubectl get po -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[*].state.waiting.reason}'`, although be aware that it only _intermittently_ shows up there, since it is an intermittent state of the container; perhaps a more programmatic approach is to examine the `restartCount` and the `Error` state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify I am posting a community wiki answer.

> It's hiding in  [`ContainerStateWaiting.Reason`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/core/v1#ContainerStateWaiting):

```
kubectl get po -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[*].state.waiting.reason}'
```

> although be aware that it only  *intermittently*  shows up there, since it is an intermittent state of the container; perhaps a more programmatic approach is to examine the  `restartCount`  and the  `Error`  state

See also [this repository](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/go/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1PodStatus.md).